# Parse arbitrary JSON with Spark's from_json

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
~ ❯ head example.csv
ix,value
1,{"abc": {"name": "bob", "profession": "engineer"}}
2,{"def": {"name": "sarah", "profession": "scientist"}, "ghi": {"name": "matt", "profession": "doctor"}}
```

The `value` column contains JSON blobs. As you can see, each JSON blob itself is of the form {A:B} where A is a random/arbitrary string, and B is a relatively well-formed JSON object.

The result I wish to obtain from this is:

```
ix,names,professions
1,[bob],[engineer]
2,[sarah,matt],[scientist,doctor]
```

To then explode into this:

```
ix,name,profession
1,bob,engineer
2,sarah,scientist
2,matt,doctor
```

Because I don't know the possible keys of A, I am having difficulty parsing the JSON blob into a StructType (I cannot enumerate all the possible keys) or MapType (not supported by from_json):

```
>>> rdd.withColumn('parsed', F.from_json(F.col('value'), MapType(StringType(), MapType(StringType(), StringType(), False), False)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/gberger/Projects/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1800, in withColumn
    return DataFrame(self._jdf.withColumn(colName, col._jc), self.sql_ctx)
  File "/Users/gberger/Projects/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
  File "/Users/gberger/Projects/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'jsontostructs(`value`)' due to data type mismatch: Input schema map<string,map<string,string>> must be a struct or an array of structs.;;\n'Project [id#35, value#36, jsontostructs(MapType(StringType,MapType(StringType,StringType,false),false), value#36, Some(Europe/London)) AS parsed#46]\n+- Relation[id#35,value#36] csv\n"
```

I know I could use a UDF, but it would severely impact performance; I wish to keep within native Spark functions if possible.

Comment: You don't really have an option, other than `udf` / conversion to `RDD`.

Comment: I don't agree that the json is of the form `{A:B}`, it's more like `{A:B <, An:Bn ...>}` where `<>` is optional. It is valid json yet horrendous. It was generated without thought of schema because it would need to enumerate all possible keys as you mentioned. The important point is you don't care about the `"abc", "def", "ghi"` keys. The form you want to get it to is an array of struct of 2 strings e.g. `ArrayType( StructType([ StructField("name", StringType()), StructField("profession", StringType())]))` can't avoid something slow like udf json lib or some horrific regex.

Comment: I thought maybe you could use `get_json_object` and use a jsonpath expression like `$..name` to get a new array column with all the names and then `$..profession` for a second array column, then zip them together and explode them, something worth trying.

Comment: Did you ever work around this?

Comment: @Datanovice No...

Answer (score -3):

You can use something like:

first define your schema:

```
jsonSchema = StructType([ StructField("name", StringType(), True),
                          StructField("profession", StringType(), True)
                        ])

df = df.withColumn("value", from_json(df["value"], jsonSchema))
```

select json properties and form dataframe

```
df = df.select("value.name", "value.profession")
```

Hope this answers your query.

Comment: import following packages:

from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

Comment: This does not answer the question. The column `value` does not conform to the schema you suggested.